# color bar value spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, spacing, colorbar

I'm using a set of data which feature values that fall between .01% and 14% and I'm attempting to make a color bar which includes the values .01, .1, 1.5 and 14.  I thought setting the values on the color bar would have them spread out equally from one color point to the next but I was wrong..  Here's what I currently have is there a simple command that would allow for these values to be shifted so they are separated by the same amount of space?

```
heat=plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto',interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot)
cbar = fig.colorbar(heat, ticks=[.1, 1,6, 14], orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Edit your question to tag the language you are using - that way people who know that language and could help will be able to find your question!

Comment: You'd have to consider how it would scale between those numbers. It might be difficult to interpret if those numbers spaced evenly on the color bar.

Comment: You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.